# fbgraph: undefined method `encode_json' for true:TrueClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nomethoderror, facebook-graph-api

My code:

```
  def start
    redirect_to client.authorization.authorize_url(:redirect_uri => callback_oauth_url,
                                                   :scope => "email,user_birthday,user_hometown,user_interests,user_location,user_notes,user_status,sms,publish_stream")
  end
  
  def callback
    access_token = client.authorization.process_callback params[:code], :redirect_uri => callback_oauth_url
    session[:access_token] = access_token
    render :json => client.selection.me.info! # <-- HERE IS THE ERROR >.<
  end
```

I went to `/oauth/start/` and successfully signed in and allowed my app. Afterwards, Facebook redirected me back to my app, which gave this error:

> ## NoMethodError in OauthController#callback
>
> ```
> undefined method `encode_json' for true:TrueClass
> ```

We all hate errors and so do I. How can I fix this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `info!` method returns an instance of `FBGraph::Result`, you need to call `data` on it so that Rails can encode it into JSON.
The following code works fine for me :

```
render :json => client.selection.me.info!.data
```